# IE8 removes background-color of header row of Asp:Gridview

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using Asp.net 4.0 GridView control to display data from database. I have applied the inbuilt theme to GridView.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="4" EmptyDataText="No records found."
    ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" Width="99%" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanged"
    PageSize="50" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" /></asp:GridView>
```

I tried setting the CSS forcefully in my Master page

```
        .GridHeader { background-color:#1C5E55 !important;}
```

But I am still missing the background-color.

I can see the backgroundcolor applied to grid (for less-than 1 sec) while the page loading the js/css content

NOTE: I already tried clearing cache of IE, ctrl + F5, shift + reload etc.

Here is sample page of my issue.

http://vd2.weenggs.com/Items.aspx

email: test@test.com

pass: test

---

```
.PACP-box:before, .PACP-box:after, .PACP-box-body:after, .PACP-box-body:before
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
bottom: 0;
content: " ";
line-height: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

I find the above CSS block causes the style render/override issue.I can not remove this block because it causes layout break.

Can anyone have the alternate CSS for the above block. ?
​

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see `#1C5E55` in the header. I don't see any `GridHeader` class defined in HTML. `BackColor` defined in `HeaderStyle` is coded throw `tr`'s style attribute. As you mentioned, you color is overridden by ecmascript code. You can easily check this by disabling ecmascript. Then you will know if the problem is in CSS or scripting.

Comment: sorry but I don't know the word "ecmascript". Can you tell me how to disable it ?

Comment: Ecmascript is another name for a JavaScript. You can disable it by F12 > Disable > Script.

Comment: I tried disabling javascript for page.no luck.. same color-less grid.
I also double checked the code.. "GridHeader" class is there just before <body> tag

Comment: GridHeader is declared in CSS, but not used in HTML. I can reproduce described behavior. It looks like a bug in IE8 render mode. But the simple case works fine http://jsfiddle.net/QmC28/show/. Try a background-image workaround or simplify CSS.

Comment: Hi, I found the css which causes the issue on IE.. 

.PACP-box:before, .PACP-box:after, .PACP-box-body:after, .PACP-box-body:before
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

If I remove this css block then grid renders just fine.but it also break the expected layout

Comment: Is there any alternate CSS which doesn't break the layout and does not overwrite the grid design. ? style is added [http://jsfiddle.net/QmC28/1/]

Comment: Great. I tried track inherited styles by parent divs but without success. I reported that IE Dev Tools do not track CSS styles applied by CSS pseudo classes - https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/749777/developer-tools-do-not-trace-styles-applied-by-pseudo-class-rules

Answer (score 0):

Give BackColor="the color you want" it works for All browsers. but you wont be able to give gradient to the header